# UIButton - alloc initWithFrame: vs. buttonWithType:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Given (arbitrarily):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f);
```

What's the difference between the following two code snippets?

1.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = frame;
```

2.

```
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 16):

I think they're equivalent. Haha! Trick question you sneaky little punk!

#### Reasoning

1. `-buttonWithType:` returns an autoreleased `UIButton` object.
2. `+[NSObject alloc]` defaults scalar instance variables to `0`, so `buttonType` should be `0`, or `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

#### Pros & Cons

1. You could argue that it's clearer to use `-buttonWithType:` and set `buttonType` explicitly and that it's safer in case Apple changes `UIButtonTypeCustom` to be `1` instead of `0` (which will most certainly never happen).
2. On the other hand, you could also argue that it's clear & safe enough to use `-initWithFrame`. Plus, many of the Xcode sample projects, such as "TheElements" & "BubbleLevel," use this approach. One advantage is that you can explicitly release the `UIButton` before the run loop for your application's main thread has drained its autorelease pool. And, that's why I prefer option 2.

Comment: "-[NSObject init] defaults scalar instance variables to 0" No, it's actually `+alloc` that sets instance variables to 0. "so buttonType should be 0" No, this depends on what `-[UIButton init]` (if there is such a method) does. Sure, it might currently set it to 0 or doesn't set it (in which case it would be 0); but since that method it not documented, they could change its behavior in the future. You have no guarantees on what it does.

Comment: I know this is old but I have noticed you have to use `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` are your button type never gets set. Also you've written `-buttonWithType` as an instance method it should be a class method so you need to replace `-` with `+`.

Comment: Also if you're subclassing, you have to use the initWithFrame method.

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly suggest using the first approach (`+buttonWithType`), because that's the only way to specify the button type.

If you `+alloc` and `-initWithFrame:`, the `buttonType` is set to some standard value (not sure which, and this could change in later versions of the SDK) and you can't change the type afterwards because the `buttonType` property is read only.

Answer (score 2):

The main (maybe the only) difference is in memory management: as you said, `buttonWithType` returns an autoreleased `UIButton`. This way you don't have to worry about releasing it. On the other hand, you don't own it, so you cannot release it when you want to (except, of course, if you `drain` the autorelease pool). 
Calling explicitly `[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame]`, instead, you dynamically alloc your button, so you own it and you're responsible for releasing it. 
If you plan to retain your button for some reason then maybe you should consider the second solution, but if, as in this case, you are autoreleasing it immediately, there's no big difference between the two way of creating a button...

Answer (score 0):

Two options are the same but I prefer option 2 because it can handle memory management

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first and do "[button retain];", so you will never lose the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I've went through the `UIButton` documentation, and here what i've found:

> Discussion
>   This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. If you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. ***If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly***.

I guess this is the trick. The `alloc-initWithFrame` is for subclasses.