# Add Subview to self.tableView.tableHeaderView does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController` and I want to extend the `tableHeaderView` of that table a bit.

So in `viewDidLoad` I added the following:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 60.0f)];
```

Fine, works well - I got my header view.

Now I want to add a Button on top of that view. So I add the following code:

```
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f)];
[someButton setTitle:@"Filter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:someButton];
```

But the button don't appear on the `tableHeaderView`. When I run the same code with a `UILabel` instead of a `UIButton` I can see the label.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: As a note: the first line in the above code will lead to a leak in a non-ARC application. Just an FYI for anyone copying and pasting this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question: [UIButton - alloc initWithFrame: vs. buttonWithType:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245882/initwithframeframe-vs-uibutton-buttonwithtype/6245883#6245883)

I recommend you use `UIButton *someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];` or something similar to that.